# How to use Delphi compiled DLL in TCL?

Tags: delphi, dll, tcl

I have been using Delphi and TCL for a while, for two different purposes. Now, I have some set of functionality which I have implemented in Delphi. I want to reuse the functionality in the TCL utility. TCL program is not a standalone program, it is being used to do scripting in a CAD tool.

The functionality being talked here is related to specific XML parsing and I have found that TCL has package to read/write XML files. However, I am thinking if I could reuse the whole logic as is.

I did Google searches on the topic but could find most of the help related to the creating TCL wrappers for TCL, however that is for C/C++. Please guide on calling the exported functions in the TCL code.

Comment: For what i remember TCL is a basis of hi-preformant e-Bay webserver. I think it already have a hi-speed XML processing libraries.

Comment: Yes, TCL is having libraries for XML. What I meant was, I didn't want to write all the logic(additional to reading/writing the XML) again in TCL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing about binary interop, is that it does not matter what language is used to create the DLL. For the sake of argument, let us consider a function declared like this, in C++:

```cpp
int __stdcall foo(double bar);
```

And suppose also that this function was exported from a DLL. Now consider this Delphi function:

```pascal
function foo(bar: Double): Integer; stdcall;
```

And again, suppose it is exported from a DLL.

Now, these two DLLs are indistinguishable from each other, at least in their interfaces. If you can call the C++ DLL from TCL then you can call the Delphi DLL.

The bottom line of all this is that since you already know how to call C++ DLLs from TCL, you can use the exact same mechanism to call Delphi DLLs. Your question is really based on an incorrect premise that a C++ DLL needs different treatment from a Delphi DLL.

The only extra information you may need is understanding of mappings between C++ and Delphi interop, for which I refer you to Rudy Velthuis's excellent article: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Comment: I'd just replace `C++` with `C` here everywhere: with `C++`, where you have classes, exported names gets mangled (and different compilers use different mangling schemes), and where a DLL compiled from `C++` code should look "normal", exported `C++` top-level function declarations are wrapped in an `export "C" { ... }` block. So for simplicity I'd just use `C` here everywhere.

Comment: @kostix Well, it is perfectly possoble to interop with C++ and C++ is a different language from C. Obviously you have to follow interop rules. That goes without saying, and nothing here suggests that use of C++ classes. Finally, using mangled names is actually not a bad idea. It does mean that everything breaks when you accidentally change a function's declaration. A useful side effect.